# What is all this about this file structure in Rails rspec Spec/request/*_spec.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

is there any different between structure of Rspec in Rails. I think there should be file structure like spec/features but I don't get it. Instead of it I get spec/request. What is this all about will some be answer me please. Whenever I try to run any file inside that folder I get error. For example,

```
describe "Signup Page" do
   visit signup_url
   fill_in "Name"
   fill_in "Email"
  end
```

All this(visit, fill_in) are capybara function. But this function doesn't run when I put in same folder or file structure i.e. spec/request

Answer (score 0):

Specs for requests and specs for features are two completely different types of tests.
Take a look at this page https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec